# How to get foreign key data in main field Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, foreign-keys

I have a problem connecting to the data for searching the customer's name because I only identify the id as a foreign key. How can I get data from the customer table? I tried using a join table but no got no result.

```
public function render()
{
    $search = $this->searchTerm;
    $data = Order::with('customer')->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('customer_id', 'like', '%' . $search . '%') // <- this field linked in customers table to get name of customer
                ->orWhere('orderNumber', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
        })->orderBy('id', $this->sortDirection)->paginate(9);
    return view('livewire.dashboard.orders.list-order', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] PS Please use standard spelling & punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right I think you are trying to search for customer name through **customer relationship**
You can do it like this:

```
      $search = $this->searchTerm;
      $data = Order::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with(['customer' => 
      function($query) use($search){  
          $query->where('name','like', '%' . $search . '%')
             ->orWhere('orderNumber', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
      }])->orderBy('id', $this->sortDirection)->paginate(9);
```